# Issue with AS 5.0.0 and BAM 2.0.0 when I create a new tenant in AS

Tags: wso2, application-server, wso2-bam

When in AS 5.0.0 I create a tenant if BAM statistic bundle is disable all work great, I can login into the tenant. But if I activate the BAM statistic bundle and try to login into the same tenant I see this error in console:

```
[2012-10-15 18:17:53,653]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged out at [2012-10-15 18:17:53,0653]
[2012-10-15 18:18:03,306] jorgeio@cdae.uci.cu [2] [Application Server] INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'jorgeio@cdae.uci.cu [2]' logged in at [2012-10-15 18:18:03,306-0400]
[2012-10-15 18:18:03,327]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.TenantAxisConfigurator} -  Creating tenant AxisConfiguration for tenant: cdae.uci.cu[2]
[2012-10-15 18:18:03,450]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.stratos.landing.page.deployer.LandingPageWebappDeployer} -  Product landing page not found.
[2012-10-15 18:18:03,565] @carbon.super [2] [Application Server]ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.utils.TenantAxisUtils} -  Error occurred while running deployment for tenant cdae.uci.cu
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.bam.service.data.publisher.publish.StreamDefinitionCreatorUtil.getStreamDefinition(StreamDefinitionCreatorUtil.java:30)
        at org.wso2.carbon.bam.service.data.publisher.internal.ServiceStatisticsAxis2ConfigurationContextObserver.setEventingConfigDataSpecificForTenant(ServiceStatisticsAxis2ConfigurationContextObserver.java:76)
        at org.wso2.carbon.bam.service.data.publisher.internal.ServiceStatisticsAxis2ConfigurationContextObserver.createdConfigurationContext(ServiceStatisticsAxis2ConfigurationContextObserver.java:51)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.utils.TenantAxisUtils.createTenantConfigurationContext(TenantAxisUtils.java:326)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.utils.TenantAxisUtils.getTenantConfigurationContext(TenantAxisUtils.java:121)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.utils.TenantAxisUtils.getTenantAxisConfiguration(TenantAxisUtils.java:101)
        at org.wso2.carbon.activation.module.ActivationHandler.invoke(ActivationHandler.java:90)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:168)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:169)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTransportSender.java:45)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.commons.stub.loggeduserinfo.LoggedUserInfoAdminStub.getUserInfo(LoggedUserInfoAdminStub.java:187)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.AbstractCarbonUIAuthenticator.setUserAuthorizationInfo(AbstractCarbonUIAuthenticator.java:278)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.AbstractCarbonUIAuthenticator.processUserAuthorization(AbstractCarbonUIAuthenticator.java:196)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.DefaultCarbonAuthenticator.authenticate(DefaultCarbonAuthenticator.java:198)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.DefaultCarbonAuthenticator.authenticate(DefaultCarbonAuthenticator.java:121)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.CarbonUILoginUtil.handleLogin(CarbonUILoginUtil.java:331)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.CarbonSecuredHttpContext.handleSecurity(CarbonSecuredHttpContext.java:223)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:58)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:179)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:49)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
[2012-10-15 18:18:03,579] @carbon.super [2] [Application Server]ERROR {org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine} -  Failed to determine Activation status.
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Failed to determine Activation status.
        at org.wso2.carbon.activation.module.ActivationHandler.invoke(ActivationHandler.java:96)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:168)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:169)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTransportSender.java:45)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.commons.stub.loggeduserinfo.LoggedUserInfoAdminStub.getUserInfo(LoggedUserInfoAdminStub.java:187)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.AbstractCarbonUIAuthenticator.setUserAuthorizationInfo(AbstractCarbonUIAuthenticator.java:278)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.AbstractCarbonUIAuthenticator.processUserAuthorization(AbstractCarbonUIAuthenticator.java:196)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.DefaultCarbonAuthenticator.authenticate(DefaultCarbonAuthenticator.java:198)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.DefaultCarbonAuthenticator.authenticate(DefaultCarbonAuthenticator.java:121)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.CarbonUILoginUtil.handleLogin(CarbonUILoginUtil.java:331)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.CarbonSecuredHttpContext.handleSecurity(CarbonSecuredHttpContext.java:223)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
       at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:58)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:179)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:49)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create tenant ConfigurationContext for tenant cdae.uci.cu
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.utils.TenantAxisUtils.getTenantConfigurationContext(TenantAxisUtils.java:124)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.utils.TenantAxisUtils.getTenantAxisConfiguration(TenantAxisUtils.java:101)
        at org.wso2.carbon.activation.module.ActivationHandler.invoke(ActivationHandler.java:90)
        ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Error occurred while running deployment for tenant
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.utils.TenantAxisUtils.createTenantConfigurationContext(TenantAxisUtils.java:335)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.utils.TenantAxisUtils.getTenantConfigurationContext(TenantAxisUtils.java:121)
        ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.bam.service.data.publisher.publish.StreamDefinitionCreatorUtil.getStreamDefinition(StreamDefinitionCreatorUtil.java:30)
        at org.wso2.carbon.bam.service.data.publisher.internal.ServiceStatisticsAxis2ConfigurationContextObserver.setEventingConfigDataSpecificForTenant(Se
rviceStatisticsAxis2ConfigurationContextObserver.java:76)
        at org.wso2.carbon.bam.service.data.publisher.internal.ServiceStatisticsAxis2ConfigurationContextObserver.createdConfigurationContext(ServiceStatis
ticsAxis2ConfigurationContextObserver.java:51)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.utils.TenantAxisUtils.createTenantConfigurationContext(TenantAxisUtils.java:326)
        ... 49 more
```

Answer (score 0):

We have come across this issue and fixed it. This is available in the [WSO2 AppServer 5.0.1](http://wso2.com/products/application-server/)  release.

Amila.

Comment: just to check, that release is in this url: http://wso2.com/products/application-server/   5.0.1?

Comment: Yes. We have hosted it there.